# "find" output relative to directory

Tags: find

I'd like to use `find` to list all files and directories recursively in a given root for a `cpio` operation. However, I don't want the root directory itself to appear in the paths. For example, I currently get:

```
$ find diskimg
diskimg
diskimg/file1
diskimg/dir1
diskimg/dir1/file2
```

But, I'd like to get

```
file1
dir1
dir1/file2
```

(note the root is also not in my desired output, but that's easy to get rid of with `tail`).

I'm on OS X, and I'd prefer not to install any extra tools (e.g. GNU find) if possible, since I'd like to share the script I'm writing with other OS X users.

I'm aware this can be done with `cut` to cut the root listing off, but that seems like a suboptimal solution. Is there a better solution available?

Comment: ```find diskimg/* | cut -d '/' -f2-```

Comment: `cut -c9-` should be faster

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`cd` into the directory first:

```
cd diskimg && find .
```

On completion, you will be back in your root directory.

Your files will be prepended with ./ in this case; the only way I see around that would be using `cut`:

```
{ cd diskimg && find .; } | tail -n +2 | cut -c 3-
```

Use a subshell to avoid changing your shell's current directory (this isn't necessary if you're piping the output as the left-hand side of a pipe already runs in a subshell).

```
(cd diskimg && find .)
```

Comment: to be back in the original dir on completion: add parenthesis: `(cd diskimg && find . ; )` . That way the `cd diskimg && find .` is done in a subshell : when that subshell exits you are back to your own shell, in whatever directory you were.

Comment: ```find *``` is another way around the useless prefix

Answer (score 44):

Another, more complex but only using find approach from my other answer:

```
find diskimg -mindepth 1 -printf '%P\n'
```

Comment: Not all versions of `find` support `printf`.

Comment: Surely; My OSX doesn't, it seems.  Partly why I offered another solution.

Comment: @Stephan - next time you can just combine these types of answers into a single one. No need to make multiple answers for variances such as this.

Comment: Only GNU `find` supports `-printf`, while many BSD `find`s have copied some of the features of GNU `find`, none has copied `-printf` yet (AFAIK).

Comment: the `%P` for the relative path was what i needed.

Comment: This is exactly the way to go for finds which support it.

Answer (score 33):

Use the `realpath` utility:

```
find diskimg -exec realpath --relative-to diskimg {} \;
```

Comment: Neat - thanks for showing me `--relative-to`.

Comment: `unknown predicate --relative-to` in CentOS 7.8

Comment: if your files are symlinks this might not give you what you want

Answer (score 24):

If what you are trying to do is not too complex, you could accomplish this with sed:

```
find diskimg | sed -n 's|^diskimg/||p'
```

Or `cut`:

```
find diskimg | cut -sd / -f 2-
```

Comment: you can choose (almost) any separator for the command, so: `find diskimg | grep -v '^diskimg$' | sed -e 's|^diskimg/||'` (note I added also '-e', and a `^` as good practice (not necessary here, as you are sure every lines will have this... but still good practice, and saves some cpu ;))

Comment: another way without grep:  `find diskimg | sed -e 's|^diskimg/*||' ` (the '/*' will match any number of '/', even 0)

Comment: This `cut` command is cleaner than the one I used; I like it. (The `sed` solution is nice too, but the repetition of `diskimg/` is a little unfortunate).

Comment: `cut -c9-` should be faster. the prefix is constant